# TypeError: Failed to parse URL from process.env.UPSTASH_REDIS_REST_URL

Tags: typescript, next.js, redis

I am getting a problem with a typescript when creating a new Redis instance. I have created an .env.local file with the same names for redis url and token

```
import { Redis } from '@upstash/redis'

export const db: Redis = new Redis({
  url: process.env.UPSTASH_REDIS_REST_URL,
  token: process.env.UPSTASH_REDIS_REST_TOKEN
})
```

This is an error :

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(requesters: Requester): Redis', gave the following error.
  Argument of type '{ url: string | undefined; token: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to     parameter of type 'Requester'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'url' does not exist in type 'Requester'.ts(2769)
(property) url: string
UPSTASH_REDIS_REST_URL
```

So what can i do ?

I've tried to look up here and there but the error stays....

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that your environment variables isn't `undefined` before using them:

```js
if (process.env.UPSTASH_REDIS_REST_URL == null)
  throw new Error('Env UPSTASH_REDIS_REST_URL not set!')
if (process.env.UPSTASH_REDIS_REST_TOKEN == null)
  throw new Error('Env UPSTASH_REDIS_REST_TOKEN not set!')
```